# Speeding up field access in R reference classes

Tags: r, reference-class

I have been writing code using [R reference classes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/refClass.html). However, as I have progressed, the program has become intolerably slow. To demonstrate the problem, take the following example:

```
myClass <- setRefClass(
  "Class"="myClass",
  fields=c(
    counter="numeric"
  ),
  methods=list(
    initialize=function () {
      counter <<- 0
    },
    donothing=function () {

    },
    rand=function () {
      return(runif(1))
    },
    increment=function () {
      counter <<- counter + 1
    }
  )
)

mc <- myClass()
system.time(for (it in 1:500000) {
  mc$donothing()
})
system.time(for (it in 1:500000) {
  mc$rand()
})
system.time(for (it in 1:500000) {
  mc$increment()
})
```

It takes:

- 4s for calls to a method
- 7s for calls to generate a random number
- 19s to increment a field value

It's the last result that's causing me problems. I obviously don't expect it to take twice as long to increment a number than to generate a random number. My code involves a lot of accessing and changing of field values in a reference class, and this performance issue has made the program all but usable.

My question: **is there anything I can do to improve the performance of field lookup/access in R reference classes? Is there anything I should be doing differently?**

Comment: I don't know, but I'm suspicious of the `<<-`.  Is that really the right way to increment a reference class field ??

Comment: @BenBolker I believe so, the documentation page says "Note that non-local assignment is required". I can't see any other obvious way of doing it. Reading the [assignment documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html), it says `<<-` causes "a search to made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned" I suspect this is where the performance hit lies.

Comment: You don't have to use non-local assignemtns as you can use `.self$<fieldname>` or `.self$field(<fieldname>)`. But that doesn't really speed up things either. Good question!

Answer (score 3):

It seems a major performance issue was due to providing class names in the `fields` argument. If I replace

```
fields=c(
    counter="numeric"
),
```

with

```
fields=c("counter")
```

the calculation completes in 5s, compared to 19s. It is difficult to determine from the documentation why the performance penalty is so great -- perhaps it is due to checking of classes during assignment. The [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/refClass.html) mentions the following:

> In particular, fields with a specified class are implemented as a special form of active binding to enforce valid assignment to the field

I'm not too sure what 'active binding' is, but I assume it introduces some pre-assignment logic.

Comment: I presume that `fields=c("counter")` is equivalent to `c(counter="ANY")`