# How to speed up writing to a matrix in a reference class in R

Tags: r, matrix, reference-class

Here is a piece of R code that writes to each element of a matrix in a reference class. It runs incredibly slowly, and I’m wondering if I’ve missed a simple trick that will speed this up.

```
nx = 2000
ny = 10
ref_matrix <- setRefClass(
   "ref_matrix",fields = list(data  = "matrix"),
)
out <- ref_matrix(data = matrix(0.0,nx,ny))
#tracemem(out$data)
for (iy in 1:ny) {
   for (ix in 1:nx) {
      out$data[ix,iy] <- ix + iy
   }
}
```

It seems that each write to an element of the matrix triggers a check that involves a copy of the entire matrix. (Uncommenting the tracemen() call shows this.) Now, I’ve found a discussion that seems to confirm this:
https://r-devel.r-project.narkive.com/8KtYICjV/rd-copy-on-assignment-to-large-field-of-reference-class 
and this also seems to be covered by [Speeding up field access in R reference classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665838/speeding-up-field-access-in-r-reference-classes)
but in both of these this behaviour can be bypassed by not declaring a class for the field, and this works for the example in the first link which uses a 1D vector, b, which can just be set as b <<- 1:10000. But I’ve not found an equivalent way of creating a 2D array without using a explicit “matrix” instance.

Am I just missing something simple, or is this actually not possible?

Let me add a couple of things. First, I’m very new to R, so could easily have missed something. Second, I’m really just curious about the way reference classes work in this case and whether there’s a simple way to use them efficiently; I’m not looking for a really fast way to set the elements of a matrix - I can do that by not having the matrix in a reference class at all, and if I really care about speed I can write a C routine to do it and call it from R.

Here’s some background that might explain why I’m interested in this, which you’re welcome to ignore.

I got here by wanting to see how different languages, and even different compiler options and different ways of coding the same operation, compared for efficiency when accessing 2D rectangular arrays. I’ve been playing with a test program that creates two 2D arrays of the same size, and calls a subroutine that sets the first to the elements of the second plus their index values. (Almost any operation would do, but this one isn’t completely trivial to optimise.) I have this in a number of languages now, C, C++, Julia, Tcl, Fortran, Swift, etc., even hand-coded assembler (spoiler alert: assembler isn’t worth the effort any more) and thought I’d try R. The obvious implementation in R passes the two arrays to a subroutine that does the work, but because R doesn’t normally pass by reference, that routine has to make a copy of the modified array and return that as the function value. I thought using a reference class would avoid the relatively minor overhead of that copy, so I tried that and was surprised to discover that, far from speeding things up, it slowed them down enormously.

Answer (score 1):

Use `outer`:

```r
out$data <- outer(1:ny, 1:nx, `+`)
```

Also, don't use reference classes (or R6 classes) unless you actually need reference semantics. KISS and all that.

Comment: Thanks. That's a really elegant way of achieving the effects of the loop in my code, and I can use that to get a very efficient piece of code in my final program! But the underlying question (which I may have obscured by the way I phrased things) was "assuming I really do want to make use of reference semantics - KISS notwithstanding - is there a way I can set up a matrix in a reference class so I can then access that matrix efficiently, element by element?"